# Web scrape events vom nvd.nist.gov from the current day

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape only the vulnerabilities published on the current day from nvd.nist.gov. In then example below the url with the cve-2022-25890 has the published date on 01/09/2023 but with "if currentday in date or if currentday == date" i get only no match why?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-25890"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
VDP = soup.find(id="vulnDetailPanel")
date = VDP.find_all("span", attrs={'data-testid':'vuln-published-on'})
print(date)

currentday = '"vuln-published-on">01/09/2023'

if currentday in date:
   print("match")
else:print("no match")`
```

i was expecting this:
[01/09/2023]
match

instead i only get this:
[01/09/2023]
no match

I also changed currentday to '01/09/2023' or '[01/09/2023]' with the same outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.find()` to find only first element (instead of `.find_all()`) and also use `.text` property:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-25890"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
VDP = soup.find(id="vulnDetailPanel")
date = VDP.find("span", attrs={"data-testid": "vuln-published-on"}).text  # <-- use find() and .text

currentday = "01/09/2023"

if currentday in date:
    print("match")
else:
    print("no match")
```

Prints:

```
match
```